# What preposition should I use? "Cartels lead to 20-30% higher prices in/on/at/for... public procurement"

Tags: prepositions

> "Cartels lead to 20-30% higher prices in/on/at/for... public procurement"

What preposition should I use?

I mean, as a result, eventual prices are higher to that extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
Cartels lead to 20-30% higher prices in public procurement.
```

This means "goods or services bought through public procurement will cost 20-30% more due to the presence of cartels".

```
Cartels lead to 20-30% higher prices for apples.
```

This means "the apples will cost 20-30% more due to the presence of cartels".

You don't want 'at' or 'on' here to say what you mean, though there are some idiomatic prepositional phrases in common use that could make sense in context and that start with those:

```
Cartels lead to 20-30% higher prices at market.
Cartels lead to 20-30% higher prices on average.
```